# Find the coefficient of $x^{9\ }$ in$\left(1+x\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{3}\right)...\left(1+x^{100}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

This is a question from binomial theorem. How do i approach these problems, can we find the coefficient of any arbitrary power of x, if there is some particular concept linked to these problems? Please help

Comment: Why do you need to use the binomial theorem? Can't you just expand?

Comment: @KentaS is it viable to expand it in case of higher power of x?

Comment: @Vega It's actually not such a big task to expand until you find the coefficient of $x^9$. Note that all the factors after $(1+x^9)$ become irrelevant, as to get an $x^9$ term we *cannot* multiply by any term $x^n$ where $n\geqslant 10$.